# Terra (LUNA) get list of transactions NodeJs

Tags: node.js, blockchain, terra-blockchain

I research the Terra (LUNA) blockchain and use js library (@terra-money/terra.js). But I can't find the method for getting list of transactions.
How can I get transaction by wallet address using NodeJs?

Answer (score 2):

you need to go via the FCD, there is a example from testnet:

```
https://bombay-fcd.terra.dev/v1/txs?offset=0&limit=100&account=<ACCOUNT>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Here’s an example from code I’ve done. https://github.com/petegordon/terra-nft-scrape/blob/7aea30462b116d70d4c3a5c628ff14b6194c6dbd/tx_nft.mjs#L164

Comment: Is there a way to get the full list of transactions instead of the 100 last ones?